# Interpolation of weighted average using distance (latitude and longitude)

Tags: interpolation, stata, nearest-neighbor

I want to compute for each municipality the weighted average of temperatures of the nearest weather stations around. I have data on the latitude and longitude of each station and each municipality.

I tried to do it with command mipolate but it allows to do it only in one dimension.

I computed a spatial weights matrix using distance with command spatwmat but it doesn't seem to be compatible with commands such as mipolate.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks !

PS: I use STATA 14

Comment: Cross-posted on https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1426344-interpolation-of-weighted-average-using-distance-latitude-and-longitude.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late for an answer but better late than never.

Fortunately, I faced this problem last year when I was tasked with crating a weather data set for more than 750 districts (similar to county level in your case) with only 120 weather stations data available in Vietnam. Before going to the solution, let's just describe my data.

What needed was 2 separated data file. The first one is the longitude, latitude for each districts, the second one is for each weather stations. The district data consists of 750 observations, each observation presents 1 district. The same for the weather stations data.

My solution was to calculate the distance between each districts to each weather stations. This information will then can be used to determine the weight for each stations for each district. Example: the temperature from station A, which only 3 km away from district A will have larger weight than station A, which 30 km away. How to calculate the weight is depends on you with the calculated distance data. I calculated all this but my professor insist to use only the data from the nearest station due to the complicated Vietnam's terrain. Thus for my case, only a simple *drop if distance <= 50* (km) were used.

Now to the *how to do that* part. First, use the district data as a base data for Multiple to Multiple (m:m) merging with the station data. By using m:m merging, each districts will be merged with 120 weather stations. Thus, result is a data file contains 750*120 observations, and 4 main variables on latitude, longitude for each districts and weather stations. With that coordinates on hand, nothing will stop us from calculating the needed distance.

What are we looking for is called Haversine formula. Which calculate the distance between two known coordinates, with longitude and latitude express in radian unit.

[Here is the formula (I just joined so I still don't know to to emblem Latex code to comment yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQpxO.gif)

If your data format is currently in degree, minute format, you can covert to radian unit by using the following code in STATA (degree and minute is express in separated variables).

```
gen radian_longtitude_station = (                        ///
                                 (degree_longtitude*3600 ///
                                  +                      ///   
                                  minute_longtitude*60   ///
                                 )/3600                  ///
                                )*_pi/180 

gen radian_latitude_station = (                      ///
                               (degree_latitude*3600 ///
                                +                    ///   
                                minute_latitude*60   ///
                               )/3600                /// 
                              )*_pi/180
```

After this, you can apply the coordinates to the formula and calculate the distance for each observation, with Earth's radius is *r* = 6,371 km, *phi_1* (*lambda_1*) and *phi_2* (*lambda_2*) is the latitude and longitude in radian for each points.

Since you are using STATA, use can use the package called *sphdist*, created by Bill Rising for this particular problem with Haversine formula. See  https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s372502.html for more information.
The usage is pretty straightforward:

```
sphdist, lat1(radian_latitude_district)   ///
         lon1(radian_longtitude_district) ///
         lat2(radian_latitude_station)    ///
         lon2(radian_longtitude_station)  ///
         radians   ///
         units(km) ///
         gen(distance)
```

Finally, what we have is a dataset as follow

```
District | Station | Distance | (Weather variables) ...
  A      |   C     |     2    |
  A      |   D     |    10    |
  A      |   F     |   300    |
  B      |   C     |      200 |
  B      |   D     |        1 |
  B      |   F     |       30 |      ........................
```

Now it's up to you to decide how to calculate the weight base on the distance between each district and each station.

[Here is the link to my example dataset:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wggjkq2077asgsb/weather_example_Dinh_Nguyen.dta?dl=0) (weather variables are not included to save space)

Hope you find this helpful. It's 5 a.m here haha, sorry if I had made any mistake in grammar.